# Trouble with running a react + next.js project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I'd like to fork this repository and run it on my local server:
https://github.com/carbon-app/carbon.git

I am familiar with React but new to Next.js. The scripts in the package.json are specified as follows:

```
"scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
```

How can I run this as a React project using npm? I'm interested in the React part to recreate another app using this app's frontend.
Please help me to run as a react project.

Answer (score 2):

first, you should install dependencies:

`npm i`

then run next js in development mode using:

`npm run dev`

for more details, visit [Next.js docs](https://nextjs.org/docs)

Comment: Thank you. I tried `npm start` earlier but it didn't work. `npm run dev` is working. How will it affect production? do you have any idea?